# How should I design the path of images for sitemap

Tags: image, seo, sitemap, google-search, google-search-console

I have a news site that provides hundreds of images every day.

Image path was like this : http://www.example.com/img/4325235.jpg

When I check the statistics on google webmasters tools, it seems 222000 images have been commited but only 14000 of them indexed.

I thought the problem was the path, then I changed the image paths like this : http://www.example.com/img/my-image-title--4325235.jpg

When I check again, it seems worstly, 222000 images have been commited but only 7900 of them indexed.

[image]
The other commits are indexed well. Why the images have problems in this case ?

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/news/my-news-title--4325235.jpg</loc>
<lastmod>2014-09-02T08:07:18+02:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>Monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
<image:image>
<image:loc>
http://www.example.com/hdimages/my-images-title--4325235.jpg</image:loc>
<image:title>Democracy in the Twenty-First Century</image:title>
<image:caption>Democracy in the Twenty-First Century</image:caption>
</image:image>
</url>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google searched for keywords in URLs. So if your image file name contains keywords, it should reflect what is inside your images to help establishing relevancy.

Google will index pages matching user queries first and may discard the rest.

If Google can't figure out what is in your images, it will not trust them and therefore, it won't rank them.